# activeDeadlineSeconds is coming invalid

Tags: kubernetes

we are facing issue while trying to set up `activeDeadlineSeconds` on Deployment. While we see at kubectl explain, according to that; it is a valid parameter on deployment. Please refer to this image:

[image]

Now, when we try to set same parameter to deployment; it say's this is invalid. Please refer to image below:

[image]

Please let us know, if we are doing something wrong here. You can use following yaml to do quick experiments:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: test
  name: test
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: test
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: nginx
        name: nginx
        resources: {}
status: {}
```

we are trying this because in our case there is an init-container which sometimes hangs, because `activeDeadlineSeconds` includes init containers too; `progressdeadlineseconds` doesn't include init containers

Is there an alternative to this?

Comment: Syntactically, `deployment.spec.template.spec` is the same as `pod.spec` (which is why you see `activeDeadlineSeconds` in `kubectl explain` output), but semantically not all the fields in a pod spec are meaningful/allowed/supported in the context of a Deployment (which is why you’re seeing the forbidden error message — under the hood, creating a Deployment results in creating ReplicaSets).

Answer (score 1):

The idea of using `activeDeadlineSeconds` on a Deployment means that you want to run something that will not last for too long. This goes against the purpose of having a Deployment. A Deployment is meant for things you want to last.

As [Amit Kumar Gupta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1061413/amit-kumar-gupta) explained:

> Syntactically, `deployment.spec.template.spec` is the same as
>   `pod.spec` (which is why you see `activeDeadlineSeconds` in `kubectl
>   explain` output), but semantically not all the fields in a pod spec
>   are meaningful/allowed/supported in the context of a Deployment (which
>   is why you’re seeing the forbidden error message — under the hood,
>   creating a Deployment results in creating ReplicaSets).

If we check the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.18/) we can see that `activeDeadlineSeconds` is available for Jobs and Pods only.

Jobs and Pods are meant to run a task and die after if finishes.

> activeDeadlineSeconds
>
> Specifies the duration in seconds relative to
>   the startTime that the job may be active before the system tries to
>   terminate it; value must be positive integer

If you are considering to set `activeDeadlineSeconds` it means that you don't want you Deployment Pods to last and this is a wrong approach.

> Is there an alternative to this?

It really depends on why your application needs this approach. If you really think this approach makes sense, you can open an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new/choose) and make a feature request for this.

Comment: we are trying this because in our case there is an init-container which sometimes hangs, because `activeDeadlineSeconds` includes init containers too; `progressdeadlineseconds` doesn't include init containers

Comment: You are trying to solve your problem or cover it? Why your init-container is hanging?

Comment: we are trying to solve it as its very intermittent that some random script will fail due to some pvc or some other resource getting unavailable. So, we all we want to restart pod if init-container has hanged due to any issue.

Comment: You have to keep in mind that by trying something like this, you are wasting resources.

Comment: what resource is wasted here? if an init container does not complete in expected time; restart/kill it. I would have expected this behavior to be in k8s itself.

Comment: Every time your Pod tries to start and init-container failed resources where used for this failed attempt. If you fix your problem instead of covering it, your cluster will have more resources to run real work. Imagine if you have this kind of approach on many applications along you cluster, you can have huge waste of resources.

Comment: This is not covering any issue in application. This is safeguarding application  from random cluster/node level issues. IMO, whole point of self healing systems is, it should be able to recover from failures and maintain availability. I see this as missing feature in k8s.

Comment: I understand. As I mentioned, if you really think this makes sense and might be helpful to others, I encourage you to go ahead and open an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new/choose).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an alternative to this?

It's a pretty simple linux task that could be solved using [`timeout`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) or [`timelimit`](https://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/) binary.

```
$ timeout -k 1 5 bash -c "while true ; do sleep 1 && echo 1 ; done" || echo
# the above task will be terminated in 5 secs or killed in 6 secs.

# timeout [OPTION] DURATION COMMAND [ARG]...
# -k, --kill-after=DURATION also send a KILL signal if COMMAND is still running
    this long after the initial signal was sent (not available on some containers)
# DURATION is a floating point number with an optional suffix: 's' for
#   seconds (the default), 'm' for minutes, 'h' for hours or 'd' for
#   days.  A duration of 0 disables the associated timeout.
# the above task will be terminated in 5 secs or killed in 6 secs.


$ timelimit -t 5 -T 1 bash -c "while true ; do sleep 1 && echo 1 ; done" || exit 0
# the above task will be terminated in 5 secs or killed in 6 secs.

# -t 5 - five seconds before sending SIGTERM to the process  
# -T 1 - one second after SIGTERM was sent and before sending SIGKILL
```

Just specify it in the `InitContainer` command to stop the task after some reasonable time.

To make the `InitContainer` think that the command is completed successfully even if it was terminated, add `|| echo` or `|| exit 0` to the end of the command as it shown in the example above.

`timeout` is present in the system by default (checked on busybox, ubuntu, centos, alpine), but `timelimit` isn't and could be installed by appropriate packet manager. For ex.:

```
$ apt-cache search timelimit
timelimit  - simple utility to limit a process's absolute execution time

$ apt-get -y install timelimit
```

You can find other ways to kill a process using bash commands only:

- [Kill process after it's been allowed to run for some time](https://superuser.com/questions/153735/kill-process-after-its-been-allowed-to-run-for-some-time)